# extract a few members from tar archive and pipe through network

Tags: tar, pipe, cpio

**edit: I want to extra `member01` and `member02` and directory `blah/`**

`tarball_1.tar.gz` contains directory `test/` with 20 files. I want to extract only member `test/member01` and `test/member02` and directory `blah/` and copy them to another "remote_host" using ssh/scp.

Can this be done as a one-liner?
I considered using `tar`, `pax`, or `cpio` but I guess I'm not very skilled with these utilities yet.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
tar -xzOf file.tar.gz file_you_want_to_extract | ssh user@host 'cat > /path/to/destination_file'
```

- `-x` : Extract
- `-z` : Through `gzip`
- `-f` : Take in a file as the input.
- `-O` : Extract to stdout

The `file_you_want_to_extract` is extracted from `file.tar.gz` to the standard output, piped into `ssh`, which runs `cat` on the remote host and writes its standard in to the remote `destination_file`.  Of course, you'll want to ensure you have write permission to your desired destination file on the remote host.

Comment: I was not clear in my original posting :) I need to extract more than one member, plus a directory.

Comment: should be tar -xz0f : after `f` comes archive name

Comment: Extracting multiple members will get messy if you want them to be one-liners, since extracting multiple files to stdout doesn't quite make sense.  You'll probably have to `tar` for each one you want to extract, then use `scp -r member1 member2 blah user@host:/destination/folder/` to copy them.  If you really want to make it one-line, you can concatenate all those commands with `&&`.  A more practical option is to just make a script as well that iterates through the command-line options and executes `tar` for each one and then `scp`s all of them at the end.

Comment: ahhhhh, I see. So there is no "easy" one-liner method. Thanks :-)

Comment: Alternatively, if "one-liner" is more important than "how long it takes", you can pipe the whole archive through ssh and extract the members you want on the other side "cat file.tar.gz | ssh user@host 'tar zxvf file1 file2 dir1'